# IOS App Crashes with [UITableView reloadData]

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

My application crashes and showing the error below.

Thread 0 Crashed:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b5d7b26 objc_msgSend + 6

1   UIKit                           0x339c74f4 -[UIResponder(Static) _setFirstResponder:] + 40

2   UIKit                           0x339c74f4 -[UIResponder(Static) _setFirstResponder:] + 40

3   UIKit                           0x339b3000 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 248

4   UIKit                           0x339e4e9c -[UITableView reloadData] + 224

5   CSModule                        0x001588e2 -[UIBubbleTableView reloadData]
```

I try to fix issue but did not get solution. Please help me to fix the issue.

I am have created a custom view with a label to on table cellview, when we tap on that custom view , it show a UIMenuController with copy option. My custom view handle tap gesture as below

```
-(void) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

    if (self.window == nil) {
        NSLog(@" \n\n\n\n Window is null \n\n\n\n\n\n");
        return;
    }

    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    CGRect targetRectangle = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, 2, 2, 2);

    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menuController setTargetRect:targetRectangle inView:self];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
```

If I did not handle tap gesture and do not show this UIMenuController , then it does not produce any crashes.

Crashes occurs randomly , I have implement Pull to refresh in UITableView, on pull I download previous data from server and reload tableview, at the same time I tap on the custom view in cell, some time crashes occurs.

One more thing some time crashes occurs at handleTapGesture function as bellow.

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b5d7b26 objc_msgSend + 6

1   UIKit                           0x339c74f4 -[UIResponder(Static) _setFirstResponder:] + 40

2   UIKit                           0x339c74f4 -[UIResponder(Static) _setFirstResponder:] + 40

3   UIKit                           0x339c74f4 -[UIResponder(Static) _setFirstResponder:] + 40

4   UIKit                           0x339b2f92 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 138

5   UIKit                           0x3398d958 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 308

6   UIKit                           0x3398dc46 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 102

7   CSModule                        0x0006ceb2 -[UIChatFootageTextView handleTapGesture:]

Please If you have any idea to fix the issue , then please help me to fix it.

Comment: why use label?why not button?

Comment: comment [self becomeFirstResponder]; and try.

Comment: @LithuT.V, I think label is a good way to show multi-line text as a chat message.

Comment: @Suresh I am already using  [self becomeFirstResponder]; as above code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are creating your own `UIMenuController` and not using `UITableViewDelegate methods`... `tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:` + `tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:` + `tableView:performAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:` for this?

Comment: a view that respond to a tap gesture is a button so why reinvent

Comment: just remove the [self becomeFirstResponder]; and check if it is working. Your crash log shows something related to the responder.

Comment: @meda this is not my query, well button handle touch action not TAP Event. I mean not doing reinvent.

Comment: @Suresh I already check  by removing [self becomeFirstResponder], In this case UIMenuController does not appear

Comment: @n00bProgrammer , Since In my case all rows of tableview  do not show UIMenuController, and only label (text) part of some row shows UIMenuContoller at tap gesture, That's why I thought to handle it as in a separate custom view.

Comment: @vnaren001, it is all possible with this. This is why i explicitly mentioned all 3 methods. I have a `UITableView` in one of my apps in which, I allow only the `copy` option, that too in certain rows only. Further, I manage to copy only the text part of the cells (they have many UI elements). Think about this a little, since you save on unnecessary object creation. If you need some sample code to get started, let me know.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer thanks dear My purpose is solved as below statement. At that when you comment I tried the way you described and I successfully show copy option with UIMenuController without correct position, when user select the row. I appreciate described way but I was using third party UIBubbleTableView according I create separate UIView class for each type row (text,video/picture,audio), I am handling their user interaction in these separate classes, that's why write tap event on TextUIView in this way instead of handle with tableview. Thanks for a good dialogue! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, I was getting the crash issue. As per my idea, since I was setting my custom view as first responder to show UIMenuController, that was required to visible UIMenuController. So I can't remove that statement.

To fix this, I resign to it as first responder just after the UIMenuController set as visible. Now my application does not get that random crashes.

```
-(void) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

    if (self.window == nil) {
        NSLog(@" \n\n\n\n Window is null \n\n\n\n\n\n");
        return;
    }

    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    CGRect targetRectangle = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, 2, 2, 2);

    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menuController setTargetRect:targetRectangle inView:self];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I noticed this same issue with my apps on ios8 GM. The problem seems to be that if you call reloadData on a UITableView that has no records to display (I.E newly installed app) it crashes.

I had to start checking to make sure that the number of records I was trying to display was >0 before calling the method... Personally I think this is a bug in ios8. If I ask a view to reloaddata, and there is no data, it should handle it. I should not have to evaluate the data existence before asking a view to reload.. kind of breaks the whole MVC design patterns IMO.

good luck to you all.

Answer (score 0):

The `UILabel` does not allow `becomeFirstResponder`. You have to subclass the `UILabel` to achieve this.

```
@interface CustomLabel : UILabel
@end

@implementation CustomLabel

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return (action == @selector(copy:));
}

- (void)copy:(id)sender {
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:self.text];
}

@end
```

Use this custom label and add your gesture to this.

Comment: Suresh UIMenuController is already appearing by above code, but some time it creates crash. Handing as below
interface CustomView : UIView
property (nonatomic,retain)UILableView* lbl;
end

implementation CustomView

-(void) initialize{
 self.lbl = [[UILableView alloc]init];
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return (action == @selector(copy:));
}

- (void)copy:(id)sender {
    //..
}